# c++ initialize char array member of a class with a string

Tags: c++

i have a class which has several members of char arrays, and i want to initialize this class with an array of strings which are the values of the char arrays.

```
class Product {
public:
    char productId[20];
    char productName[50];
    char price[9];
    char stock[9];

    Product(vector<string> v) : productId(v[0]), productName(v[1]), price(v[2]), stock(v[3]) {  }
};
```

with this code i get an error that say `no suitable conversion function from "str::string" to "char[20]" exist`

Comment: You will need to `strcpy` into those arrays.

Comment: ^ after checking the length will fit

Comment: Have you thought about what should happen if a `std::string` is too long to fit into its fixed character array?

Comment: At least pass the vector by reference so you don't invoke unnecessary allocations and additional copies.  If you can't guarantee safe string lengths at runtime to avoid overflowing these, consider `strncpy_s`.

Comment: thank you all for your answers, first i have no priority with memory safety or stuff like that, i'm a new learner of c++ and i'm stuck with this. Second i've tried with strcpy but i got an error like this: `a value of type "char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char [20]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code at the bottom will work. But is this a good idea? Probably not. You are better of just storing `std::string` in your `Product` type directly:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <string.h>

class Product {
public:
  std::string productId;
  ...

  Product(std::vector<std::string> v) : productId{std::move(v[0])} {}
};
```

There is a problem with this code though; where do you check the vector has all required elements? Better to make an interface that specifies the four strings a `Product` is made up of separately:

```
class Product {
public:
  std::string productId;
  ...

  Product(std::string pid, ...) : productId{std::move(pid)}, ... {}
};
```

But in case you insist on a C/C++ amalgamation;

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

#include <string.h> // strcpy

class Product {
public:
  char productId[20];
  char productName[50];
  char price[9];
  char stock[9];

  Product(const std::vector<std::string> &v) {
    assert(!v.empty()); // really; v.size() == 4
    ::strncpy(productId, v[0].c_str(), 19);
    productId[19] = '\0';
    // ...etc.
  }
};
```

Comment: In your last example, you should use `(std::)strncpy()` instead to avoid potential buffer overflows, and should ensure the data is actually null-terminated, eg: `strncpy(productId, v[0].c_str(), 19); productId[19] = '\0';`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, I've updated the answer.